# how to make a UIScrollView track something?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uiscrollview

i want my app to be able to track a person when he moves 2 dimensionally upwards. I already have a vertical scroll view, and it works, but when i press a button i want it to track a little stick figure as he walks vertically, how can i control this? i thought of setting the scrollview.contentoffset to a certain position, but it just changes it one time when i want it to change it fluidly. i suppose i could make a timer that updates the contentOffSet every like .001 seconds or something, but i thought there maybe a better way.

---

Also, while i was searching the UIScrollView's methods, one of them was an isTracking method, which is a boolean, and I'm assuming it returns yes if the scrollview is tracking something, so given that i assume there is a feature in scrollview so that you can track things. Also, if to track things you have to use some other framework thing that would be helpful to know too

THANKYOU FOR ANY HELP!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The property [`tracking`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006922-CH3-SW3) tells if the scroll view is currently tracking the user's movement. So that definitely won't help you out. (See David H's post for a better explanation for what the property indicates.)

However, you could use [`setContentOffset:animated:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006922-CH3-SW1) and set `animated` to `YES`. That results in a smooth transition to the new content offset.

Instead of calculating a reasonable content offset you might find it easier to specify an area that contains the stick figure. If so use [`scrollRectToVisible:animated:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006922-CH3-SW26). Obviously `animated` should be set to `YES`.

Answer (score 1):

1) don't use contentOffset = x;, use "- (void)setContentOffset:(CGPoint)contentOffset animated:(BOOL)animated". Experiment how often you need to send this message, but I'm guessing  you can do it no more than 10 times a second and get nice results.

2) isTracking means the user has their finger on the scrollView but has not started dragging it. By testing "isTracking" and "isDragging" you can determine if the user is fiddling with your scrollView or not.